# SSE Intrinsics arithmetic error

Tags: c, gcc, intel, sse, simd

I've been experimenting with SSE intrinsics and I seem to have run into a weird bug that I can't figure out. I am computing the inner product of two float arrays, 4 elements at a time.

For testing I've set each element of both arrays to 1, so the product should be == size.

It runs correctly, but whenever I run the code with size > ~68000000 the code using the sse intrinsics starts computing the wrong inner product. It seems to get stuck at a certain sum and never exceeds this number. Here is an example run:

```
joe:~$./test_sse 70000000
sequential inner product: 70000000.000000
sse        inner product: 67108864.000000
sequential          time: 0.417932
sse                 time: 0.274255
```

Compilation:

```
gcc -fopenmp test_sse.c -o test_sse -std=c99
```

This error seems to be consistent amongst the handful of computers I've tested it on. Here is the code, perhaps someone might be able to help me figure out what is going on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <xmmintrin.h>

double inner_product_sequential(float * a, float * b, unsigned int size) {

  double sum = 0;

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sum += a[i] * b[i];
  }

  return sum;

}

double inner_product_sse(float * a, float * b, unsigned int size) {

  assert(size % 4 == 0);

  __m128 X, Y, Z;

  Z = _mm_set1_ps(0.0f);

  float arr[4] __attribute__((aligned(sizeof(float) * 4)));

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i += 4) {

    X = _mm_load_ps(a+i);
    Y = _mm_load_ps(b+i);

    X = _mm_mul_ps(X, Y);
    Z = _mm_add_ps(X, Z);

  }

  _mm_store_ps(arr, Z);

  return arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[2] + arr[3];

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

  if(argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: ./test_sse <size>\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  unsigned int size = atoi(argv[1]);

  srand(time(0));

  float *a = (float *) _mm_malloc(size * sizeof(float), sizeof(float) * 4);
  float *b = (float *) _mm_malloc(size * sizeof(float), sizeof(float) * 4);

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    a[i] = b[i] = 1;
  }



  double start, time_seq, time_sse;


  start = omp_get_wtime();

  double inner_seq = inner_product_sequential(a, b, size);

  time_seq = omp_get_wtime() - start;


  start = omp_get_wtime();

  double inner_sse = inner_product_sse(a, b, size);

  time_sse = omp_get_wtime() - start;


  printf("sequential inner product: %f\n", inner_seq);
  printf("sse        inner product: %f\n", inner_sse);
  printf("sequential          time: %f\n", time_seq);
  printf("sse                 time: %f\n", time_sse);




  _mm_free(a);
  _mm_free(b);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you're running out of precision?

Comment: Did you notice that 67108864 is 2^26? Do you think that's just a coincidence?

Comment: Are you compiling in 32-bit more or 64-bit mode?

Comment: I did notice that the sum was 2^26... but the question that I guess I was trying to ask was whether the SSE instructions used the same precision registers as regular instructions in the FPU. I got a little confused because I didn't realise that I had declared sum as a double in the first function as Christoph Freundl pointed out. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into the precision limit of single precision floating point numbers. The number 16777216 (2^24), which is the value of each component of the vector `Z` when reaching the "limit" inner product, is represented in 32-bit floating point as hexadecimal `0x4b800000` or binary `0 10010111 00000000000000000000000`, i.e. the 23-bit mantissa is all zeros (implicit leading 1 bit), and the 8-bit exponent part is 151 representing the exponent 151 - 127 = 24. If you add a 1 to that value this would require to increase the exponent but then the added one cannot be represented in the mantissa any longer, so in single precision floating point arithmetic 2^24 + 1 = 2^24.

You do not see that in your sequential function because there you are using a 64-bit double precision value to store the result, and as we are working on a x86 platform, internally most probably an 80-bit excess precision register is used.

You can force to use single precision throughout in your sequential code by rewriting it as

```
float sum;

float inner_product_sequential(float * a, float * b, unsigned int size) {
  sum = 0;

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sum += a[i] * b[i];
  }

  return sum;
}
```

and you will see `16777216.000000` as maximum computed value.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It was actually an oversight that I declared sum as a double. The question that came to mind was whether the SSE instructions use the same 80-bit registers for floating point operations for each packed value that the FPU uses for normal instructions.

Comment: SSE instructions use different registers than scalar floating point instructions. The SSE registers are 128 bit wide, which can contain four single precision values as in your example.

Comment: Right, but what I'm asking about is whether each of the four packed floats in the 128bit SSE register are processed through an extended precision 80 bit register for their respective op? Because if not, one might experience compounded round-off and overflow errors for the same computation executed with SSE instructions versus single value instructions. Or is the loss of precision in intermediate values the tradeoff to using SSE?

Comment: In short, your last question is in fact the answer. x87 and SSE are just different architectures using different registers and instructions. Note that you can also perform double precision arithmetics as of SSE2.